# Javafx Task<ObserveableList>.updateValue only fires first change event

Tags: multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

I'd like to observe a task's valueProperty, and take action when it's changed by updateValue().  The change event only seems to get fired on the first update though.

[Oracle's getValue document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#getValue--) has a section implying that it's kosher to repeatedly call UpdateValue to return partial results.  Perhaps I'm not understanding what they mean by "updates are coalesced".

### Minimum Example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    MyTask task = new MyTask();
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(listView));
        primaryStage.show();

        Thread taskThread = new Thread(task);
        taskThread.start();

        task.valueProperty().addListener( (ob,old,nw) -> listView.getItems().addAll(nw) ); // Only fires once.
        //task.lastString.addListener( iv -> listView.getItems().addAll(task.lastString.getValue()) ); // Fires every add
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}

class MyTask extends Task<ObservableList<String>> {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<String> lastString = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(new String());
    Integer maxWork = 4;

    @Override
    protected ObservableList<String> call() throws Exception {
        for( Integer stringNo=0; stringNo<maxWork; stringNo++) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            String addMe = new String("Thread string " + stringNo);
            list.add(addMe);
            updateProgress(stringNo, maxWork);
            updateValue(list);   // Only fires one change event
            Platform.runLater( () -> {
                lastString.setValue(addMe); // Works as expected.
                 } );
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `value` of the task only changes once. Initially it is `null`. On the first iteration it changes so the `value==list` and on every subsequent iteration, `value==list` (i.e. there are no further changes).

You probably want to:

1. Update the list on the FX Application thread, by calling `Platform.runLater(() -> list.add(addMe));`
2. Arrange to observe the list itself, instead of the task's `value` property.

Comment: Thanks!  You're quite right, I was mistaking the Task's valueProperty<ObservableList> for the task's ObserveableList.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming along later, here's the code, modified to provide direct access to the listView itself.

```
package demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class Main extends Application {
    MyTask task = new MyTask();
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(listView));
        primaryStage.show();

        task.lv = listView;
        Thread taskThread = new Thread(task);
        taskThread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class MyTask extends Task<ObservableList<String>> {
    ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<String> lastString = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(new String());
    Integer maxWork = 4;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected ObservableList<String> call() throws Exception {
        updateValue(list); // make sure that the task's valueproperty has a value.
        Platform.runLater(() -> addMyListener());


        for (Integer stringNo = 0; stringNo < maxWork; stringNo++) {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            String addMe = new String("Thread string " + stringNo);
            list.add(addMe);
            updateProgress(stringNo, maxWork);
            updateValue(list);   // Only fires one change event
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                lastString.setValue(addMe); // Works as expected.
            });
        }
        return list;
    }

    void addMyListener() {
        ObservableList<String> obl = valueProperty().getValue();
        obl.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> c) {
                while (c.next()) {
                    List added = c.getAddedSubList();
                    Platform.runLater(() -> lv.getItems().addAll(added));
                }
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Original answer states: _"here's the code, modified to provide direct access to the listView itself"_. Why should MyTask know about some GUI element?!? That is not its responsibility. Tight coupling will make architecture disappear and maintenance of that code base will become nightmare by doing things like this...

Comment: Point taken. MCVE doesn't care about architecture.